# How do you create a DropShadow on a UIView

Tags: iphone, uikit, uiview

My current code doesn't seem to do anything:

```
CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(currentContext);

float myColorValues[] = {1.0, 0, 0, .8};
CGColorSpaceRef myColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGColorRef myColor = CGColorCreate(myColorSpace, myColorValues);
CGContextSetShadowWithColor (currentContext, CGSizeMake(-1, -1), 0, myColor);

//CGContextSetShadow(currentContext, CGSizeMake(-15, 20), 15);


[super drawRect: rect];

CGContextRestoreGState(currentContext);
```

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962827/uiimage-shadow

Comment: Check out this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805872/how-do-i-draw-a-shadow-under-a-uiview

Comment: You should never call drawRect directly. Use setNeedsDisplay so the contexts are properly setup.