# Create new UIImage by adding shadow to existing UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage, cgcontext

I've taken a look at this question: [UIImage Shadow Trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962827/uiimage-shadow)

But the accepted answer didn't work for me.

What I'm trying to do is take a UIImage and add a shadow to it, then return a whole new UIImage, shadow and all.

This is what I'm trying:

```
- (UIImage*)imageWithShadow {

    CGColorSpaceRef colourSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef shadowContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, self.size.width, self.size.height + 1, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(self.CGImage), 0, 
                                                 colourSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colourSpace);

    CGContextSetShadow(shadowContext, CGSizeMake(0, -1), 1);
    CGContextDrawImage(shadowContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height), self.CGImage);

    CGImageRef shadowedCGImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(shadowContext);
    CGContextRelease(shadowContext);

    UIImage * shadowedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:shadowedCGImage];
    CGImageRelease(shadowedCGImage);

    return shadowedImage;
}
```

The result is that I get exactly the same image as before I put it through this method.

I am doing this the correct way, or is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: If the UIImage will be shown in a UIImageView, you can also just add a shadow effect to the view. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044479/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-shadow-behind-a-uiimageview

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

- The target image is too small. Be sure there enough place to draw the shadow.
- Consider using `CGContextSetShadowWithColor` to define both the shadow and its color.
- Don't forget that coordinate system is flipped, so the origin is bottom-left, not top-left.

By fixing these issues, the shadow should be drawn.

```
- (UIImage*)imageWithShadow {
    CGColorSpaceRef colourSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef shadowContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, self.size.width + 10, self.size.height + 10, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(self.CGImage), 0, 
                                             colourSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colourSpace);

    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(shadowContext, CGSizeMake(5, -5), 5, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextDrawImage(shadowContext, CGRectMake(0, 10, self.size.width, self.size.height), self.CGImage);

    CGImageRef shadowedCGImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(shadowContext);
    CGContextRelease(shadowContext);

    UIImage * shadowedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:shadowedCGImage];
    CGImageRelease(shadowedCGImage);

    return shadowedImage;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I was actually adding 1 to the height to draw the shadow, but the other stuff (setting the shadow, flipped coordinate system) was spot on.

Comment: Where would this code be implemented and how would you call it to add a shadow to an image?

Comment: The method assumes that the class can provide a CGImage and its dimensions. You can alter the method to take parameters (CGImage and CGSize) instead.

Comment: How to convert an UIImage to CGImage ?

Comment: @user403015: use the CGImage property of UIImage.

Answer (score 13):

Swift extension to UIImage:

```
extension UIImage {
    
    func addShadow(blurSize: CGFloat = 6.0) -> UIImage {
                    
        let shadowColor = UIColor(white:0.0, alpha:0.8).cgColor
        
        let context = CGContext(data: nil,
                                width: Int(self.size.width + blurSize),
                                height: Int(self.size.height + blurSize),
                                bitsPerComponent: self.cgImage!.bitsPerComponent,
                                bytesPerRow: 0,
                                space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
                                bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)!
        
        context.setShadow(offset: CGSize(width: blurSize/2,height: -blurSize/2),
                          blur: blurSize,
                          color: shadowColor)
        context.draw(self.cgImage!,
                     in: CGRect(x: 0, y: blurSize, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height),
                     byTiling:false)
        
        return UIImage(cgImage: context.makeImage()!)
    }
}
```

(converted from Laurent Etiemble's & capikaw answers)

Usage:

```
let sourceImage: UIImage(named: "some image")
let shadowImage = sourceImage.addShadow()
```

Answer (score 5):

I needed a method that would accept an UIImage as a parameter and return a slightly larger UIImage with shadows. The posts here have been very helpful to me so here's my method.

The returned image has a centered 5px shadow on each side.

```
+ (UIImage*)imageWithShadowForImage:(UIImage *)initialImage {

    CGColorSpaceRef colourSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef shadowContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, initialImage.size.width + 10, initialImage.size.height + 10, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(initialImage.CGImage), 0, colourSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colourSpace);
    
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(shadowContext, CGSizeMake(0,0), 5, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextDrawImage(shadowContext, CGRectMake(5, 5, initialImage.size.width, initialImage.size.height), initialImage.CGImage);
    
    CGImageRef shadowedCGImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(shadowContext);
    CGContextRelease(shadowContext);
    
    UIImage * shadowedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:shadowedCGImage];
    CGImageRelease(shadowedCGImage);
    
    return shadowedImage;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I needed a bigger shadow for my UIImages.  Here is my variant of the answer that allows for a customized shadow size with no offset.

```
- (UIImage*)imageWithShadow:(UIImage*)originalImage BlurSize:(float)blurSize {     
    CGColorSpaceRef colourSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef shadowContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, originalImage.size.width + (blurSize*2), originalImage.size.height + (blurSize*2), CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(originalImage.CGImage), 0, colourSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colourSpace);
    
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(shadowContext, CGSizeMake(0, 0), blurSize, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextDrawImage(shadowContext, CGRectMake(blurSize, blurSize, originalImage.size.width, originalImage.size.height), originalImage.CGImage);
    
    CGImageRef shadowedCGImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(shadowContext);
    CGContextRelease(shadowContext);
    
    UIImage * shadowedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:shadowedCGImage];
    CGImageRelease(shadowedCGImage);
    
    return shadowedImage;
}
```

Use it like:

```
UIImage *shadowedImage = [self imageWithShadow:myImage BlurSize:30.0f];
```

Answer (score 5):

Whilst trying to use some of the other examples here, I noticed that they seem to either hard-code the offset & blur, or do not correctly take them into account when sizing and positioning the output.

The following code solves these issues (it's based on the original work by Igor Kulagin):

```
extension UIImage {
    /// Returns a new image with the specified shadow properties.
    /// This will increase the size of the image to fit the shadow and the original image.
    func withShadow(blur: CGFloat = 6, offset: CGSize = .zero, color: UIColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.8)) -> UIImage {

        let shadowRect = CGRect(
            x: offset.width - blur,
            y: offset.height - blur,
            width: size.width + blur * 2,
            height: size.height + blur * 2
        )
        
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(
            CGSize(
                width: max(shadowRect.maxX, size.width) - min(shadowRect.minX, 0),
                height: max(shadowRect.maxY, size.height) - min(shadowRect.minY, 0)
            ),
            false, 0
        )
        
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

        context.setShadow(
            offset: offset,
            blur: blur,
            color: color.cgColor
        )
        
        draw(
            in: CGRect(
                x: max(0, -shadowRect.origin.x),
                y: max(0, -shadowRect.origin.y),
                width: size.width,
                height: size.height
            )
        )
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

My method that draws a shadow on an image. It has custom shadow parameters and renders image in correct size and screen scale. Should be implemented in UIImage extension. (Swift 3).

```
func addingShadow(blur: CGFloat = 1, shadowColor: UIColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 1), offset: CGSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1) ) -> UIImage {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: size.width + 2 * blur, height: size.height + 2 * blur), false, 0)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

    context.setShadow(offset: offset, blur: blur, color: shadowColor.cgColor)
    draw(in: CGRect(x: blur - offset.width / 2, y: blur - offset.height / 2, width: size.width, height: size.height))
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make an image a `CGImage` as in this case , try

```
self.shadowImage.CGImage
```

Answer (score 0):

GK100's answer in Swift 2 / iOS9

```
func addShadow(blurSize: CGFloat = 6.0) -> UIImage {

    let data : UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> = nil
    let colorSpace:CGColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()!
    let bitmapInfo : CGBitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue)

    let myColorValues:[CGFloat] = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.8]
    let myColor = CGColorCreate(colorSpace, myColorValues)

    let shadowContext : CGContextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, Int(self.size.width + blurSize), Int(self.size.height + blurSize), CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(self.CGImage), 0, colorSpace, bitmapInfo.rawValue)!

    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(shadowContext, CGSize(width: blurSize/2,height: -blurSize/2),  blurSize, myColor)
    CGContextDrawImage(shadowContext, CGRect(x: 0, y: blurSize, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height), self.CGImage)

    let shadowedCGImage : CGImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(shadowContext)!
    let shadowedImage : UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: shadowedCGImage)

    return shadowedImage
}
```