# How do I create a white border and black shadow for my UIImageView?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

How do I create a white border and black shadow for my UIImageView?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just import

```
#import  <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

and make sure that you have the QuartzCore framework added to your project.

Then to add border

```
[imageView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
[imageView.layer setBorderWidth: 2.0];
```

To create shadow, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962827/uiimage-shadow-trouble) SO question, which will get you going..

Comment: Just make sure that you import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> and make sure that you have the QuartzCore framework added to your project.

Comment: That is the right way to add the border using quartz core framework....+1 for you...

Comment: yes @Rexeisen, forgot about includes and frameworks..Thanks for noting that..Will edit my answer..

Comment: ok.After this my problem is,How to access the jailbreak iphone root directory.My main theme is set the wallpaper for everymonth.And get that wallpaper from database.assign and storing to database is completed.But how to access the jail break iphone.Please give me the right direction for doing this one.please

Answer (score 3):

this is the way I add a border and shadow to an UIImage in a UIMageView

```
someImageView.image = someUIImage;
someImageView.frame = CGRectMake(45, 25, 50, 50);
[someImageView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
[someImageView.layer setBorderWidth: 2.0];
[someImageView.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(-3.0, 3.0)];
[someImageView.layer setShadowRadius:3.0];
[someImageView.layer setShadowOpacity:1.0];
```

remember:

```
#import  <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Comment: And also remember to set someImageView.clipsToBounds = NO.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add it as another UIImageView behind the one showing your image.